# How would you say "Dog Lover" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-término, animales

How would you say "Dog Lover", as in "Person who likes dogs, and may be looking to adopt a dog"?

I feel like "Fanático" is wrong, and "persona a quien le caen bien los perros" is too long.

"Amante" is right out.

Comment: Besides *amante* there's also *aficionado*, but a more modern option is *fan de los perros*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do say "amante de los perros," but please note that "amante" will be an adjective, not a noun, there (no article allowed), being thus similar to "fond of."

Therefore, a highly likely sentence will be:

> Es **amante** de los perros

We can also use a verb:

> **Ama / Adora** a los perros

Comment: But what about "Cualquier amante de los perros te dirá etc."?  Surely there we see that it's clearly a noun.  The way I learned it was that we omit the article, not because the word isn't a noun, but just because... well, because in Spanish we omit the article in simple linking phrases such as "He is a teacher" = "Es maestro".

Comment: @aparente001 Now that I read your comment, I've had second thoughts. The word "amante" can be an adjective or a noun, and we could say in fact say "es **un** amante de los perros", which is slightly more emphatic than the more usual "es amante de los perros". With "maestro", we can use the article when we mean that somebody is a genius or an expert in some field: "Es **un** maestro".

Comment: Sorry, *maestro* was just some convenient example.  Inconvenient, as it turns out.   Let me try again.  "Raúl es albañil."  // I agree, "amante" can be both adjective or noun.  (That was an interesting sentence!  It shows that the omission of the article in a simple sentence of the form *noun = noun* is also possible in English!)

Answer (score 1):

***Un aficionado de los perros*** then, if *un amante de los perros* is out.